# How to get the custom key elements from fire base database in Android?

Tags: android

I have the following fire base database structure
[Data base Structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOFJs.jpg)

and i am succeed in getting the following result on my emulator 
[Output of my Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfE2A.jpg)

The problem is that I am getting stuck in getting the data that is in my custom key i.e. Group Name I don't know how to bring that specific data which is in my key i want to show my users only group name that is in the custom key the reason behind saving that in keys is that one user of my application will be able to create multiple groups therefore i have put that data in custom key such that whenever a user create a new group from his/her account so there data will be saved in a unique key. The sample code for my view fragment is that

```
public static final String TAG = "Tab2Fragment";
private ListView Lview;
private DatabaseReference dref;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);

    perform(view);
    dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("Shahrukh");
    String grp_name=  dref.getKey().toString();
    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String grp_name = snapshot.getKey();

                    list.add(grp_name.toString());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    return view;
}

public void perform(View v) {
    Lview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    Lview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}